# How to resolve Invalid Cast exception?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

[image]I am facing an issue as invalid cast exception in my razor view. I have created a log in razor for authentication purpose but I am facing this issue. Can anyone suggest to resolve this issue? I have attached the code snippet and issue SS here.

**Code snippet**

```
private async Task<bool> ValidateUser()
{
    //assume that user is valid
    //call an API

    var returnedUser = await userService.LoginAsync(user);
    
    if(returnedUser.EmailAddress != null)
    {
        await sessionStorage.SetItemAsync("emailAddress", returnedUser.EmailAddress);
        await sessionStorage.SetItemAsync("token", returnedUser.Token);

        ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthenticated(user.EmailAddress);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/index");
    }
    else
    {
        LoginMesssage = "Invalid username or password";
    }

    return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Comment: Apparently `AuthenticationStateProvider` is not a subclass of (and/or does not implement) `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider`. To resolve the issue, remove the cast or ensure that the object you're casting is actually of the type you're casting it to.

Comment: Post the part of Startup where you register the provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This is the ValidateUser method's code from the sample you provided link to:

```
private async Task<bool> ValidateUser()
{
    //assume that user is valid
    //call an API

    var returnedUser = await userService.LoginAsync(user);
    
    if(returnedUser.EmailAddress != null)
    {
        await sessionStorage.SetItemAsync("emailAddress", returnedUser.EmailAddress);
        await sessionStorage.SetItemAsync("token", returnedUser.Token);

        ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthenticated(user.EmailAddress);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/index");
    }
    else
    {
        LoginMesssage = "Invalid username or password";
    }

    return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Clearly this call to MarkUserAsAuthenticated is wrong:

```
MarkUserAsAuthenticated(user.EmailAddress);
```

It should be:

```
MarkUserAsAuthenticated(returnedUser.EmailAddress);
```

Hope this works...

Comment: I'd advise you not to use that sample any further. The person/persons who wrote this sample need themselves learn Blazor and Asp.Net Core... You should improve your skills by going to chris sainty's and Blazor university's web sites.

Comment: But in  login async method in user service class I am facing an issue like "Invalid request uri was provided or the request uri must be an absolute uri or base address must be set" in the following line var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage); Can you please suggest me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: My friend, that is another issue entitled for another question. Did you try the change I've proposed ? Does it still give you the same error ? Report this...

Comment: I have changes your solution but returned user down't return any value due to the exception occuring in log in async method so I couldn't verify your solution can you suggest me to resolve this ?

Comment: Yes, comment up all the code in the LoginAsync method, except the last two. Change the code of the first line to create a new user: var returnedUser = New User {<provide values to the fields>};

            return await Task.FromResult(returnedUser);